# Log event too large: 3971758 bytes exceeds limit of 262144 - winston-aws-cloudwatch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, winston

Below is my winston and winston-aws-cloudwatch setup,

```
const winston = require("winston");
const enviornment = require("../core/environment/environment");
const CloudWatchTransport = require("winston-aws-cloudwatch");

const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || "dev";

try {
  const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
      new CloudWatchTransport({
        logGroupName: "production-group", // REQUIRED
        logStreamName: NODE_ENV, // REQUIRED
        createLogGroup: true,
        createLogStream: true,
        submissionInterval: 2000,
        submissionRetryCount: 1,
        batchSize: 20,
        awsConfig: {
          accessKeyId: enviornment.aws.accessKeyId,
          secretAccessKey: enviornment.aws.secretAccessKey,
          region: enviornment.aws.region
        },
        formatLog: (item) => `${item.level}: ${item.message} ${JSON.stringify(item.meta)}`
      })
    ]
  });

  // fix for : InvalidParameterException: Log event too large: 3162892 bytes exceeds limit of 262144
  logger.on('error', function (err) {
    logger.warn("Limit exceed", err);
  });
} catch (e) {
  logger.warn("Limit exceed error", e);
}
```

I have node/expres app and I log request and response objects using winston and morgan.

Actually response object is literally big. **It is of 4MB size** and I guess when I try to log such response objects, it throws below error and I can see in AWS cloudwatch as below,

```
Promise Rejection   
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "InvalidParameterException: Log event too large: 3971758 bytes exceeds limit of 262144",
    "reason": {
        "errorType": "InvalidParameterException",
        "errorMessage": "Log event too large: 3971758 bytes exceeds limit of 262144",
        "code": "InvalidParameterException",
        "message": "Log event too large: 3971758 bytes exceeds limit of 262144",
        "time": "2023-06-28T05:20:32.296Z",
        "requestId": "0cae7917-6087-40c4-bf0b-3a97241a9c56",
        "statusCode": 400,
        "retryable": false,
        "retryDelay": 16.887530598358104,
        ...
  }
```

To handle such exception, you can see I added `try...catch` block. Also, I added `logger.on('error',...)` line. However, it doesn't catch the exception and fails everytime.

**How should I handle it** ?